# SpagoBI URL directly

Tags: spagobi

I'm using  this URL to go directly to my document in SpagoBI but it does not work:

```
http://localhost:8080/SpagoBI/servlet/AdapterHTTP? 
PAGE=LoginPage&NEW_SESSION=TRUE&OBJECT_LABEL=DocumentName
```

It gives me the message that I should log in but i'm already logged in.

Comment: What are the login and passwords you are using

Answer (score 0):

Download SpagoBIQbeEngine separately from Downloads page (http://forge.ow2.org/project/showfiles.php?group_id=204) and deploy war file to webapps folder of your SpagoBI installation.
Wait till Tomcat automatically deploys war file and refresh the page
Good luck

Answer (score 0):

use url like one mentioned below
you need to pass username and password along with url
as you can see username and password is visible in URL for security
you can use intermediate servlet to build this url and then url.

http://localhost:8080/SpagoBI/servlet/AdapterHTTP?PAGE=LoginPage&NEW_SESSION=TRUE&OBJECT_LABEL=REPORT_NAME&userId=biadmin&password=biadmin
(only login)

if report contains filter u need to pass filter parameter as well in URL
please see url structure of GET method for better understanding for passing multiple parameters.

&PARAMETERS=report parameters

Hope this helps